# In Javascript/Jquery, how do I display a div for 5 seconds, and then have it fade out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, when someone clicks on a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the delay function available since 1.4

From the docs: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
$('#foo').fadeIn(400).delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function:

```
$(something).delay(5000).fadeOut();    //5,000 milliseconds
```

In general, you can call `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //Do things...
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In 1.4 you can use the `.delay()` function. Here's the documentation for that:

[jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Alternately you could look into the native javascript `setTimeOut()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the JQuery 1.4+, you could try

```
$('#myDiv').fadeIn('medium').delay(5000).fadeOut('medium');
```

You can remove the fadeIn if the div is visible straight away.